# fs2 - Sharing a Ref with 2 streams

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, fs2

I'm trying to share a `Ref[F, A]` between 2 concurrent streams. Below is a simplified example of the actual scenario.

```
  class Container[F[_]](implicit F: Sync[F]) {
    private val counter = Ref[F].of(0)

    def incrementBy2 = counter.flatMap(c => c.update(i => i + 2))

    def printCounter = counter.flatMap(c => c.get.flatMap(i => F.delay(println(i))))
  }
```

In the main function,

```
object MyApp extends IOApp {

  def run(args: List[String]): IO[ExitCode] = {
    val s = for {
      container <- Ref[IO].of(new Container[IO]())
    } yield {
      val incrementBy2 = Stream.repeatEval(
          container.get
            .flatTap(c => c.incrementBy2)
            .flatMap(c => container.update(_ => c))
        )
        .metered(2.second)
        .interruptScope

      val printStream = Stream.repeatEval(
          container.get
            .flatMap(_.printCounter)
        )
        .metered(1.seconds)

      incrementBy2.concurrently(printStream)
    }
    Stream.eval(s)
      .flatten
      .compile
      .drain
      .as(ExitCode.Success)
  }
}
```

The updates made by the `incrementBy2` are not visible in `printStream`.
How can I fix this?
I would appreciate any help to understand the mistake in this code.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is broken since the class definition, you are not even updating the same `Ref`

Remember that the point of `IO` is to be a description of a computation, so `Ref[F].of(0)` returns a program that when evaluated will create a new `Ref`, calling multiple `flatMaps` on it will result in multiple `Refs` being created.

Also, your is not doing tagless final in the right way *(and some may argue that even the right way is not worth it: https://alexn.org/blog/2022/04/18/scala-oop-design-sample/)*

This is how I would write your code:

```scala
trait Counter {
  def incrementBy2: IO[Unit]
  def printCounter: IO[Unit]
}
object Counter {
  val inMemory: IO[Counter] =
    IO.ref(0).map { ref =>
      new Counter {
        override final val incrementBy2: IO[Unit] =
          ref.update(c => c + 2)
        
        override final val printCounter: IO[Unit] =
          ref.get.flatMap(IO.println)
      }
    }
}

object Program {
  def run(counter: Counter): Stream[IO, Unit] =
    Stream
      .repeatEval(counter.printCounter)
      .metered(1.second)
      .concurrently(
        Stream.repeatEval(counter.incrementBy2).metered(2.seconds)
      ).interruptAfter(10.seconds)
}

object Main extends IOApp.Simple {
  override final val run: IO[Unit] =
    Stream
      .eval(Counter.inMemory)
      .flatMap(Program.run)
      .compile
      .drain
}
```

> PS: I would actually not have `printCounter` but `getCounter`
> and do the printing in the `Program`

---

*You can see the code running [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/Wd8TioiZSQ6RyRsCugkviQ/1)*.